# laravel5.3 relationships (collections)

Tags: collections, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I've got three tables:

```
users
    -id
    -name
    -...

addresses
    -id
    -user_id
    -...

transactions
    -id
    -address_id
    -amount
```

My models look like this:

user model:

```
public function addresses()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
}
```

address model:

```
public function user()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function transactions()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction');
}
```

transaction model:

```
public function address()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Address');
}
```

Now I would like the whole sum of all transactions for a certain user.
What's the best way to archive this using eloquent?

```
  dd($forwarded_total->sum('addresses.transactions.amount'));
```

returns 0 all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relation in `User` model to get all related transactions as:

```
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Transaction', 'App\Address');
}
```

Then you can query it as:

```
$total_sum = User::find(1)->transactions->sum('amount');
```